# mysql npm module in meteor

Tags: mysql, meteor, npm

I'm playing with the npm mysql module in done to see if I can run queries against a database to extract data into a meteor.js application.

I've created a base meteor project and done sudo npm install -g mysql.

The code in the project is really simple at this stage (and that could be the problem). I have the following in my server/startup.js file

```
var mysqlDriver = Meteor.npmRequire('mysql');
var connection;

Meteor.methods({
  'connectDB': function connectDB(){
    connection = mysqlDriver.createConnection({
      host: '10.1.23.2',
      user: 'user',
      password: 'password'
    });
  },
  'queryDB': function queryDB() {
    connection.connect();
    connection.query('dl.SETTLEMENTDATE, dl.INITIALMW, dl.TOTALCLEARED,  dl.SEMIDISPATCHCAP from bocorock.DISPATCHLOAD dl  where dl.duid in ("BOCORWF1") order by dl.settlementdate desc limit 100', function(err, rows, fields) {
      console.log('err', err);
      console.log('rows', rows);
      console.log('fields', fields);
    });
  }
})
```

This is the only file in the project at the moment.

When I try and run this (meteor run) I'm getting the following errors.

```
=> Started MongoDB.     
W20140925-14:38:04.535(10)? (STDERR) 
W20140925-14:38:04.595(10)? (STDERR) /home/pnunn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.31.7wezrh++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140925-14:38:04.596(10)? (STDERR)                                            throw(ex);
W20140925-14:38:04.596(10)? (STDERR)                                                  ^
W20140925-14:38:04.596(10)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'describe'
W20140925-14:38:04.596(10)? (STDERR)     at app/server/packages/npm-container/package.js:4:11
W20140925-14:38:04.596(10)? (STDERR)     at app/server/packages/npm-container/package.js:23:3
W20140925-14:38:04.596(10)? (STDERR)     at /home/pnunn/src/meteor/mysqlTest/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
W20140925-14:38:04.597(10)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140925-14:38:04.597(10)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/pnunn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.31.7wezrh++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140925-14:38:04.597(10)? (STDERR)     at /home/pnunn/src/meteor/mysqlTest/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to look for this.

Any ideas? Am I missing something important here?

Peter.

Comment: Not making any progress with this one. I've updated to 0.9.3 and still have the same error.  meteor list shows 
autopublish      1.0.0  Publish the entire database to all clients
insecure         1.0.0  Allow all database writes by default
meteor-platform  1.1.1  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
meteorhacks:npm  1.2.0  Use npm modules with your Meteor App
npm-container    1.0.0  Contains all your npm dependencies

If that means anything to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Since Meteor uses its own package manager, it is not directly compatible with npm. To use a npm package, you need to:

- Add [meteorhacks:npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm/) package to your project.
- Create `packages.json` file in your project directory with your packages defined:

  ```
  {
    "mysql": "2.5.1"
  }
  ```
- Use `Meteor.npmRequire` instead of `require`.

Comment: Yup.. that's how it is now. See var mysqlDriver = Meteor.npmRequire('mysql');

Should have said that I am using meteorhacks:npm sorry.